# Use state from a Context inside Class component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

here is my Codepen which illustrates my current problem:
I woud like to use the class component, so I can call the forward function from parentComponents (through ref), but I currently cant figure out how to manipulate the context (Where the current state of the application is stored.
Can somebody help me ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-dust-vtp46?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1918

Kind regards

Comment: What component are you wanting to consume the context in? Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the relevant code you have an issue with?

Comment: I have its inside the codepen :D 
The working functional Component is SStateButton
But I need it as a class component and cant work through changing the state

Comment: You would need to wrap the component in a [context consumer](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer) but since the class-based component you want to consume the context value in is used in the same component providing the context (*i.e. the context state and setter*) you can more simply just enclose `setStatus` in the passed `onClick` handler.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exactly answer, but I have a solution, that you can forward function to parent component with Functional component. Check this code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';

const ChildComponent(props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    const funcCallFromParent = (params) => {
      funcToHandle(params);
    };
    return { funcCallFromParent };
  });

  const doSomething(params) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

and then call if from your ParentComponent

```
  ...
  childRef.current.funcCallFromParent(params);
  ...
```

This way will help you use Functional Component instead of Class Component, therefore easier to access the context.

Additional, maybe you'll want to try Redux, it's a good and most popular Context Management for ReactJS.

Comment: Calling the function like this is not really ideal, i feel but thanks for a possible solution.
Redux looks good and could solve my problem, I just started with react and completly missed it, vue has something very similar.
THANKS

Answer (score 0):

To consume React Context with class-based component you wrap them with the Consumer component and inject context value as props.

SStateButton

```
export class SStateButton extends Component {
  refe;
  name;
  onclick;

  constructor({
    refe,
    name,
    onclick
  }: {
    refe: Status;
    name: string;
    onclick: any;
  }) {
    super({ refe, name, onclick });
    this.refe = refe;
    this.name = name;
    this.onclick = onclick;
  }

  forwardToStatus = () => {
    if (this.onclick) {
      this.onclick(this.refe);
    }
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        className="btn btn-light btn-outline-dark"
        onClick={this.forwardToStatus}
      >
        ClassComponent {this.name}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

App - Given context value `value={[status, setStatus]}`

```
<StateContext.Consumer>
  {([, setStatus]) => (
    <SStateButton
      refe="1 Page"
      name="Go to Page 1"
      onclick={(val) => {
        console.log("Additional functions added");
        setStatus(val);
      }}
    />
  )}
</StateContext.Consumer>
```

Since `SStateButton` is being used in the same component that is providing the context value, and has the `status` state and updater function already in scope, the `setStatus` callback can also just be enclosed in the `onclick` callback and work just the same.

```
<SStateButton
  refe="1 Page"
  name="Go to Page 1"
  onclick={(val) => {
    console.log("Additional functions added");
    setStatus(val);
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Yeah thats possible but only because the val in this example is a const. In a practical way the class component would handle the data in some way (processing necessary stuff for example) and then I couldnt set it inside the SStatebutton could I ? Maybe I am missing something

Comment: @KevinKumar Yeah, TBH I don't see the point in the React ref or context usage in that codesandbox. For any of the buttons you can easily pass closed over values in the callbacks, i.e. `onClick={() => setValue("1 Page")}`, and the buttons themselves needn't any refs or extra logic to accomplish what is basically simple proxying of the values back to the handlers you defined in the `App` component with the context state. Seems a very roundabout way to do anything.

Comment: yeah you are right but a codepen is only to illustrate a problem in a simple way, as I described in my use case I need some further processing, I think use Redux there would be the easiest way tho

Comment: @KevinKumar I am certain that any "extra processing" could be closed over in the callback scope, and if it's dependent on any values from the child component those can be passed in to the callback when clicked. Redux is a state management tool so I don't think it's quite what you need unless you are referring to asynchronous actions. Perhaps if you could provide a more concrete example I might better understand your use case.

Comment: Yeah you could do that but then I could just define the function inside my parent component but my function inside the child component (where its processed and only when this component is used). Thats why defining it inside the parent component wouldnt be ideal.

As I said i want to pass a state from the parent to a class component , in a functional component I can just use the context but in my class Comp it doesnt work.

In my case my state shows the level of a memory quiz (learning phase, pause,reproduction). The Button i use is for forwarding to th next level

Comment: I am sure my implementation is just a bad practice and makes it much more complicated. A universal store for the level is just more logical, I have to do some more reading :) Thank you

Comment: Or Just creating an exported function would be a much easier way :)
But I still wonder why using a "foreign" state from a context can be used inside a functional component but not inside a class component :/ In most cases it can be solved through just a different implementation, probably thats why

Comment: @KevinKumar Using a render props function is the way to pass a context value to a consuming class-based component. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer And sure, like many things in software, there isn't always a single cut & dry way to accomplish things.